# Two ways to design complex system: Top-down vs Bottom-up

Tags: java, oop, architecture, methodology

I have a complex system to design.
I have two ways:

1. **Top-down**: I will design many interfaces and contracts. Afterwords, I will implement these interfaces, and write a prototype to verify the design.
2. **Bottom-up**: I will write code to make the system run. Afterwords, I will extract interfaces and contracts from solid code. The distilled interfaces and contracts is my design. It's rule "*make it run, make it right*".

What is better way? From my opinion, I will choose Bottom-up. Because Top-down is very difficult, no one can design many interfaces at high abstract level,at least it's hard for me. When I write solid implementation to verify the initial design, there are many unreasonable things which force me to re-design from scratch. While I use Bottom-up, I feel quite "safe", it can run at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have said, it's usually a mix. On a more practical level, the following approach usually helps:

- Start by going ABSTRACT Top-Down. Namely, break the system/design into logical components to solve tasks. But don't design precise finalized interfaces for those components. Proceed recursively till some components you arrive at are of "implementation-possible" size (e.g. are the size of a single function/method/class)
- Then, go through the resultant component list Bottom-Up, and start designing first draft of interfaces/contracts.
- Then, go through the resultant component list Bottom-Up, and start implementing them. This will allow you to:

  - Have a working and testable code immediately (no need to wait for underlying components to be implemented to test)
  - You can synthesize the final version of interfaces/contracts for higher level components based on the needs of the already-completed lower level components.

Answer (score 2):

Except in most trivial designs **nothing is ever this simplistic**. I find that most designs require a mixture of both methodologies to refine.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, top-down design is more natural than bottom-up one. E.g.: when you are designing a system, primarly you define its functionality(design interfaces and contracts), then you specify the entities of the system, implement relations among them and so on...  Certainly, top-down design is more difficult than bottom-up one, and it requires experienced  developers.

Answer (score 0):

I personally also prefer Bottom up - first because you always forget something when doing top-down and then have to fix that and second because at least in my case I get lots of good ideas for the complete system while designing the single components from bottom.

Greetings,
Lorenz

Answer (score 0):

In the real world is nearly impossibile to use these simplistic methodologies to design systems. You usally have to use both of them in multiple iterations.

But this is a simplistic answer, too.